# Some key combinations not working in OS X 10.5.8

Tags: mac, keyboard, osx-leopard

I've got an iMac running Mac OS X 10.5.8 that is ignoring a few key combinations (most of the time, that is).  Left-shift-e and left-command-c have stopped working.  It's not the physical keys as, for example, left-shift-d works just fine.  I can type E or copy using the right-hand shift and command keys.

Sometimes, and I think it's when I'm catching my computer unawares (while it's processing), left-command-c works just fine.

Is there a corrupted preference file hanging around somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I specifically noticed Left-Shift+R and Command+V not working. And now it's fixed.

One of the keys on my keyboard (0 on numeric pad) weren't properly in place. When I pressed it, it got stuck. I removed it, and placed it back where it should be. Now all key combinations work again.

Hope this might help.